# Symfony embed form with select field

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have an embed form `ClientTarifaType` inside of another one called `ClientType`. The embeded form (`ClientTarifaType`) just have one select field with the Tarifas already exists (`Client` and `Tarifa` have a ManyToMany relationship).

ClientType.php

```
        ->add('tarifas', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type'   => ClientTarifaType::class,
            'allow_add'    => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'by_reference' => false
        ))
```

ClientTarifaType.php

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('nombre', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Tarifa',
                'label' => 'Tarifa asociada a este cliente',
                'placeholder' => 'Elige tarifa...',
            ));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Tarifa',
        ));
    }
```

The issue comes when submitting because the sent form data appears a Tarifa entity inside of a field of Tarifa entity too (one entity inside of another one of the same type!), like this:

```
Tarifa {#1050 ▼
  -id: null
  -clientes: null
  -plaza: null
  -mercancia: null
  -envios: ArrayCollection {#1054 ▶}
  -pesos: array:27 [▶]
  -codigo: null
  -nombre: Tarifa {#1070 ▼
    -id: 1
    -clientes: PersistentCollection {#1076 ▶}
    -plaza: Plaza {#1129 ▶}
    -mercancia: null
    -envios: PersistentCollection {#1183 ▶}
    -pesos: PersistentCollection {#1201 ▶}
    -codigo: "00001"
    -nombre: "Canarias"
  }
}
```

I think the problem is I have the field of type Tarifa and the data_class is Tarifa type too. How can I put the select field with the nombre and id attributes only? Thanks in advance, any help is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

If you want only to select one or more Tarifa already created you dont need the form ClientTarifaType.php. http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html

```
->add('tarifas', EntityType::class, array(
     'class' => 'AppBundle:Tarifa',
     'multiple' => true, 
     //'expanded' => true,
 ))
```

If you want to create tarifas when you are creating the client at same time, you will need a collection of form: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html but I think this is not your case.

view with select2

```
<html>
<form>
    {{ form_row(form.tarifas) }}
</form>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="{{ asset('bundles/app/js/jquery.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="{{ asset('bundles/app/js/select2.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#{{ form.tarifas.vars.id }}').select2();
</scrip>
</html>
```

Comment: I just need to select multiple Tarifa, as many as the user wants, so it has to be added by jQuery. But how can I use this simple field with jQuery?

Comment: You dont need Jquery, multiple=true is for more than one, you can use expanded if you want checkboxes. With Jquery you can make it beauty. I normal use select select2, you can use optionaly if you want. I have edited my answer